# Popup menu / display new value in Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor, popupmenu

I'm stuck in Angular to display a new value.

There is a 3dots popup menu beside a value "X". In this menu, my goal is to choose a new value and to replace the value "X" with a new one, "Y" or "Z". I've tried many things with method "displayManagedByValue()" but nothing works.

Any ideas?...

```
<span>X</span>
 <!-- Popup menu-->
  <span>
   <button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="popup menu">
    <mat-icon class="popup-menu">more_vert</mat-icon>
   </button>
   <mat-menu  #menu="matMenu">
    <button *ngFor="let value of managedByValues" (click)="displayManagedByValue(value)" mat-menu-item>
     <span class="managedBy-value">{{value}}</span>
      </button>
       </mat-menu>
        </span>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-warehouse',
  templateUrl: './warehouse.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./warehouse.component.scss']
})

export class WarehouseComponent {

  managedByValues: string[] = ['Y', 'Z'];

  displayManagedByValue(value: string): void {

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i created a quick [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6vb8mm?file=src/app/menu-icons-example.ts)

html

```
<span>{{val}}</span>
 <!-- Popup menu-->
...
```

ts

```
  val = 'X';

  managedByValues: string[] = ['Y', 'Z', 'X'];

  displayManagedByValue(value: string): void {
    this.val = value;
  }
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Great! It seems so simple...

I think I've complicated my approach to this problem too much.

By the way, thank you very much for your help